# Parse big binary strings to base 10

Tags: javascript

I'm having some trouble converting big binary strings to base 10. `parseInt(string, 2)` should return the int, but when using big strings (1800 characters) it maxes out the variable and just returns `Infinity`. How can  get around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A 1800 bit binary number would be well over the [maximum possible number value in JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_max_value.asp). A regular number datatype will not be able to hold that value, and so JavaScript just calls it `Infinity`. If you need arbitrarily large numbers, you will have to use some bignum library and probably write a custom string to number function.